# Customize selectmenu jquery under id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have select using with jquery-ui

```js
$(function() {
  $("#number")
    .selectmenu()
    .selectmenu("menuWidget")
    .addClass("overflow");
});
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.overflow {
  height: 200px;
}

.ui-menu-item{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="number">Select a number</label>
<select name="number" id="number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option selected="selected">2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
  <option>7</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>9</option>
  <option>10</option>
  <option>11</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>13</option>
  <option>14</option>
  <option>15</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>17</option>
  <option>18</option>
  <option>19</option>
</select>
```

Snippet is not working, so here is fiddle link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/vgm3txh6/8/
```

When I set class like this all is okay

> .ui-menu-item{
>     font-weight: bold;
>   }

But when I need to use it under specific id , for example like this

```
> #number.ui-menu-item{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Iy not apply styles.

Where is my problem?

Comment: ID selector should start with `#` tag

Comment: I edited post, for some reasons it's clear `#` tag@Hikarunomemory

Comment: Nope, because it's not working too. Check it in fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/vgm3txh6/12/ . @Hikarunomemory

Comment: yeah, I found that I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id=number` is not the parent to the `ui-menu-item` class.
But `id=number-menu`is.

Since `>` is the parent selector,you need to use number-menu as given below,

```
#number-menu > .ui-menu-item{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Solved here: https://jsfiddle.net/vgm3txh6/41/

Comment: Thank's. Also one little question, if I have it inside of class
Like this, How I need to fix it. Here is link 

https://jsfiddle.net/vgm3txh6/45/

Comment: You can't do it since the select tag is having display:none, your actual UI is having ul and li tags. This means you need to override the css, in this case using their generated classes and ids, as given in the js.

Comment: Trick was here to select it relative to #number ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select all successive div elements after #number with class .ui-menu-item. Here is selector :

```
#number ~ div .ui-menu-item{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: It is wrapped up inside a jquery ui control so if you look with Inspect Element you will see that #number is outside jquery ui select control, like a wrapper. I will try to select it anyway.

Comment: please try it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
#number-menu .ui-menu-item{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I found that it automatically created some elements after `select#number`

and the options shown in `select#number` are in this element `ul#number-menu`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI generates new dom element so it gets new `#number-menu`.

```
#number-menu .ui-menu-item{
    font-weight: bold;

}
```